# Under Django concurrency, why does the generated snowflake ID repeat?

Tags: django

I use modules written by others, as follows:

https://github.com/tarzanjw/pysnowflake/blob/master/snowflake/server/generator.py

I first ran a single-threaded test by myself. There will be no duplication at all, and there is no duplication at all when multi-threaded locks are added.

But when I generate it in the actual project with Django, about 10 Threads submit a total of 1600 pieces of data, and about dozens of duplicates will be generated each time

I printed the ID, and this snowflake generator instance has not been repeat initialized. How can I troubleshoot?

The approximate code is as follows:

```py
from newsnow import Generator
logger = logging.getLogger('django-production')
get_flake_id = Generator(dc=0, worker=0)

def create_product_meta(prepare_product_meta):
    new_product = models.productMeta(
        own_store=prepare_product_meta.get("own_store").upper(),
        product_name=prepare_product_meta.get("product_name"),
    )
    logger.warning(id(get_flake_id))
    new_product.flake_id = get_flake_id.get_next_id()
    return new_product
```

Any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far I see, the code does not use any Snowflake object. It generates the sequences using a simple calculation:

```
 generated_id = ((curr_time - EPOCH_TIMESTAMP) << 22) | (self.node_id << 12) | self.sequence
```

It uses node_id when calculating the sequence, and it's calculated with the following formula:

```
self.node_id = ((dc & 0x03)<< 8) | (worker & 0xff)
```

So as a workaround, you may give different dc and worker values for each thread.

Or if you can use database objects, you can create a Snowflake sequence and handle the uniqueness of the seuqnce in the database side:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason has been found.

Django uses multi-process startup, and the attributes between instances are isolated from each other.

It is necessary to use pid as worker_id to physically isolate the processes.

Like this:

get_flake_id = Generator(dc=0, worker=os.getpid())